# Proof of a theorem similar to the mean value theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Prove that $\forall x_1, x_2 \in [a, b]$, there exists $c \in [a, b]$
>   such that
>   $$\frac{f(x_1) + f(x_2)}{2} = f(c).$$
>   Generalise this result to $x_1, x_2, . . . x_n \in [a, b]$.

I started by using the extreme value theorem s.t. $f$ is bounded but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: @KentaS Very helpful...

Answer (score 3):

$\frac {f(x_1)+f(x_2)+...+f(x_n)} n$ lies between the maximum $M$ and the minimum $m$ of $f$. By IVP any number between $m$ and $M$ is attained at some point $c$.

Comment: Thank you, I had a feeeling it was quite obvious.